# AdMob Ad not showing in emulator, android

Tags: android, admob

Java class code(in onCreate method):

```
AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest MyAdRequest = new AdRequest();
MyAdRequest.setTesting(true);
adView.loadAd(MyAdRequest);
```

layout/main.xml code:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="My_AD_PUBLISHER_ID" ads:adSize="BANNER"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

values/attrs.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="com.google.ads.AdView">
        <attr name="adSize">
            <enum name="BANNER" value="1" />
            <enum name="IAB_MRECT" value="2" />
            <enum name="IAB_BANNER" value="3" />
            <enum name="IAB_LEADERBOARD" value="4" />
        </attr>
        <attr name="My_AD_PUBLISHER_ID" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

In Manifest file, before application tag ends:

```
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />
```

Before manifest Tag ends:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Library has also been included from properties to Java build path
and in place of `My_AD_PUBLISHER_ID`, i have carefully placed my actual adcode

After doing all this, ad is showing, NEITHER in emulator NOW on device. pleae guide me what am i missing?

Comment: AdLoader timed out while getting ...

Comment: onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error ...

Comment: adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head>sc ...

Comment: Received ad url: <url": "http:// ...

Comment: your layout for the ad in the XML is kinda weird. align parent bottom AND center in parent? reconsider checking those over.

Comment: and 2 more repeating the first two...

Comment: looks like a network problem, are you connected to a valid network with internet access? test it out by loading up the browser

Comment: yes i am very sure that i added the actual publisher id, in both main.xml and attrs.xml, plus if i want to show my ad in the center and bottom of the app, what tags should i add, are these not good enough to do so ?

Comment: use `alignParentBottom="true"` and `centerHorizontal="true"`. `centerInParent` centers both vertically and horizontally, you just need horizontal centering it seems. also, you don't need the `this` keyword while using `findViewById`

Comment: do you mean loading up a browser in a test app? or just checking up in chrome if net is working?

Comment: make sure your ad view is not below any other views in your relative layout. add it at the end of the XML file to make sure

Comment: test the internet on the emulator itself, using the browser app

Comment: and what steps should i take then,, if my browser app is not working ?

Comment: one thing, should my project be targeting 1.6 or to show ads 1.6API is needed ?

Comment: You do not need 1.6API.  Are you using the newest AdMob jar?  Have you ever had ads show up?  Can you get ads to show up in other apps?

Comment: This question is using attrs.xml, which likely means it's using Admob 4.0.4 or older. 4.1.0 has some changes described in [this google groups discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/google-admob-ads-sdk/browse_thread/thread/3b885d3fe5bb21a5) (look for Tim's post).

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned your LogCat says:

> onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error...

this means it is a network problem. Even you can load web browse, it doesn't mean the network is okay, it might be blocked by the firewall or other network configurations. I had the same problem before.

If you try on real device instead of simulator, the test ad not showing might be caused by other admob issues other than network problem.  The most common admob issue is "No Ad to Show" error which has something to do with Admob fill rate.

Answer (score 2):

If like me you have mobile broadband you need to establish a connection on the internet prior to starting the emulator or it does not seem to get a connection

Answer (score 0):

In your resources file, I noticed you have

```
<attr name="My_AD_PUBLISHER_ID" format="string" />
```

Where it should read

```
<attr name="adUnitId" format="string" />
```

Not sure if this is a typo from when you copied to StackOverflow, or not.  I believe this would cause an build error?

Comment: so "adUnitId" should not be replaced with a PUBLISHER ID ?

Comment: done, still ad not showing up... ok one thing, should my project be targeting 1.6 or to show ads 1.6API is needed ?

Comment: In the attrs.xml you're defining the two new xml attributes to be used with AdView (adUnitId, and adSize), as well as defining their types (string an enum respectively).

This allows you to add the adUnitId, and adSize attributes to the AdView your layout xml.  And the value of adUnitID in the layout file should be your publisher id.